# doesn't progress the radius, but should

Tags: java, android, animation, canvas, geometry

I know this is the wrong way to do it, but the lack of help from anyone has caused me to do this. I have drawn 7 circles each with a different radius in the same play each pausing for 300 miliseconds after being drawn so in theory it should look like the circle is expanding as its being drawn, but for some reason its not can someone tell me why or maybe answer this question that has caused me weeks of hardache. The app displays circles randomly on the screen either green or red. When it displays a circle it really should display 7 circles instead it only displays the last one with a radius of 300.

```
public class SplashLaunch extends View{
    Handler cool = new Handler();
    DrawingView v;
    Paint newPaint = new Paint();
    int randomWidthOne = 0;
    int randomHeightOne = 0;
    private float radiusNsix = 10;
    private float radiusNfive = 25;
    private float radiusNfour = 50;
    private float radiusNthree = 100;
    private float radiusNtwo = 150;
    private float radiusNone = 200;
    private float radiusZero = 250;
    private float radiusOne = 300;
    final int redColorOne = Color.RED;
    final int greenColorOne = Color.GREEN;
    private static int lastColorOne;
    ObjectAnimator radiusAnimator;
    private final Random theRandom = new Random();
    public SplashLaunch(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private final Runnable circleUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColorOne = theRandom.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColorOne : greenColorOne;
            newPaint.setColor(lastColorOne); 
            cool.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow(){
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        cool.post(circleUpdater);
    }
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        cool.removeCallbacks(circleUpdater);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(theRandom == null){
            randomWidthOne =(int) (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs(getWidth()-radiusOne/2)) + radiusOne/2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radiusOne/2 + radiusOne/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidthOne =(int) (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs(getWidth()-radiusOne/2)) + radiusOne/2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radiusOne/2 + radiusOne/2f))));
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNsix, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNfive, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNfour, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNthree, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNtwo, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusNone, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusZero, newPaint);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne, radiusOne, newPaint);
    }




    public void setRadiusOne(float value){
        this.radiusOne = value;
        invalidate();
    }


    public int startAnimation(int animationDuration) {

        if (radiusAnimator == null || !radiusAnimator.isRunning()) {

            // Define what value the radius is supposed to have at specific time values
            Keyframe kf0 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0f, 0f);
            Keyframe kf2 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0.5f, 180f);
            Keyframe kf1 = Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, 360f);

            // If you pass in the radius, it will be calling setRadius method, so make sure you have it!!!!!
            PropertyValuesHolder pvhRotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("radiusOne", kf0, kf1, kf2);
            radiusAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, pvhRotation);
            radiusAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            radiusAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
            radiusAnimator.start();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Circle", "I am already running!");
        }
        return animationDuration;
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        if (radiusAnimator != null) {
            radiusAnimator.cancel();
            radiusAnimator = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean getAnimationRunning() {
        return radiusAnimator != null && radiusAnimator.isRunning();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please go into a bit more detail about exactly what it's doing, and exactly what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are doing - a wrong way for drawing things. You should not block UI thread in onDraw method. 
Second - circles displays in random places because you use random numbers generator, and first two arguments of [canvas.drawCircle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) is NOT width and height(if i understand your code right).

For now all UI thread is blocking on each Thread.sleep. If you really want to animate all this circles you should calculate on each call onDraw method their sizes, based on time. To give you an idea:

```
public SplashLaunch(Context context) {
    super(context);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMills();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, calculateRadius(System.currentTimeMills() - startTime), paint);
}
```

One more thing, your code displayed only last circle because you draw it last, is you want 7 circles to be displayed you need to draw it in reverse order.

Comment: i want it to be drawn last

Comment: System.currentTimeMilillis() is minusing itself the radius will always be zero

Comment: @PaulTrueman did you try to implement it in your code to say that?